# Weird Coloring in Intellij Terminal

Tags: intellij-idea

When I type the letter g in Intellij terminal the foreground and background color of the letter changes to grey. Typing the next letter changes it back to the normal colors. What could be causing this weird behavior?

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA.

Comment: (indistinguishable fore-&background or darker&lighter grey?)